# PySpark: How do I solve 'python worker failed to connect back' error when using pyproj package in Pandas UDF? (Converting lat/long to UTM coordinates)

Tags: converters, pyspark

I have a json file with lat/long coordinates, which I try to convert to UTM ("x", "y") in PySpark. 
The .json file looks like this:

```
{"positionmessage":{"latitude": 51.822872161865234,"longitude": 4.905614852905273}}
{"positionmessage":{"latitude": 51.819644927978516, "longitude": 4.961687088012695}}
```

I read the json file in pyspark and try to convert to UTM ('x', 'y'-coord) in PySpark with the following script:

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DateType, FloatType, TimestampType, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

appName = "PySpark"
master = "local"
file_name = "lat_lon.JSON"

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("positionmessage",
    StructType([
    StructField('latitude', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('longitude', DoubleType(), True),
    ]))])

df  = spark.read.schema(schema).json(file_name).select("positionmessage.*")
```

Until here no problem; the problem arises when I try to convert to UTM coordinates using the pyproj package (which worked in Pandas).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyproj import Proj
from pandas import Series

# using decorator 'pandas_udf' to wrap the function. 
@pandas_udf('array<double>', PandasUDFType.SCALAR) 
def get_utm(x):
  pp = Proj(proj='utm',zone=31,ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
  return Series([ pp(e[0], e[1]) for e in x ])

df = df.withColumn('utm', get_utm(array('longitude','latitude'))) \
  .selectExpr("*", "utm[0] as X", "utm[1] as Y")

df.show()
```

I get the problem: " python worker failed to connect back", but there does not seem to be a problem with the code itself. What can the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a plain UDF rather than Pandas UDF:

```
@udf(returnType=ArrayType(DoubleType()))
def get_utm(long, lat):
  pp = Proj(proj='utm', zone=31, ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
  return pp(long, lat)


result = df.withColumn('utm', get_utm('longitude','latitude')).selectExpr("*", "utm[0] as X", "utm[1] as Y")
```

Comment: This gives me the error: " /"cannot resolve '`positionmessage`' given input columns: [latitude, longitude]" in pyspark 2.4.5. Also, I would like to make 'latitude' and 'longitude' input to the code (Ihave other columns names too).

Comment: My fault, I missed that you had selected longitude and latitude as the input. I've edited my answer and tested it.